# .unbind() and .bind() function in hover function

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I am tring to make a hover function, which on hover, unbinds a previous binded function.

But I don't think I understand what the jquery website is trying to explain.

Please see my attempt in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/S9uVh/). http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/S9uVh/

This is my binded function which runs fine...

```
$("h1.trunc").bind().shorten({
    width: 300,
    tail: '...',
    tooltip: false 
});
```

But I am then trying to .unbind() it when my element is hovered, but the re-bind it on my second hover alternation...

```
$('#element').hover(
    function () {

        $(this).find("h1.trunc").unbind();

        $(this).animate({
            height : '100px'    
        }, 200 );       

    }, 
    function () {

        $(this).find("h1.trunc").bind().shorten({
            width: 300,
            tail: '...',
            tooltip: false
        });

        $(this).animate({
            height : '20px'    
        }, 200 );

    }
);​
```

Can someone help me fix this please. Also is there a way of not having to re-write the entire "h1.trunc" function again inside my hover function.

Please see working [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/S9uVh/). Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/S9uVh/

Comment: Minor error in css `overflow: visable;` to `overflow: visible;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at what `shorten` is actually doing, it is removing the text and there is no reverse of this method e.g. `unshorten`.

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to display the text when hovering, then truncating it again on hoveroff.

I would get rid of the `shorten` plugin, and just use css. Check out this little fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S9uVh/22/

Basically I am just removing a class, then adding it again. The `<h1>` tag is shorted using;

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;    
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: For something reason I thought text-overflow css was limited to browser support??? But just checked this and yes it seems to work in all browsers. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah it is one of these styles which you would assume wouldn't work in IE6/7 but actually does!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you seem to misunderstand some things. First of all `.bind()` left alone (i.e. without arguments) does nothing. Second of all: this `.shorten` plugin seems to alter the inner HTML, there is no `binding` with it. And it does not allow returning to previous state. So what I advice you should do this:

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="trunc" data-text="This is a truncated title to untruncate when hovered using unbind tricks"></h1>
```

Note, that I put all of the text in `data-text` attribute. Now inside your handler you do this:

**JavaScript**

```
var text = $("h1.trunc").attr("data-text");

$('#element').hover(
    function () {

        $(this).find("h1.trunc").text(text);

        $(this).animate({
            height : '100px'    
        }, 200 );       

    }, 
    function () {

        $(this).find("h1.trunc").text(text).shorten({
            width: 300,
            tail: '...',
            tooltip: false
        });

        $(this).animate({
            height : '20px'    
        }, 200 );
    }
);​
```

Checkout [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9uVh/24/). Note however that this `.shorten` plugin seems to set `nowrap` css, which makes it look bad. You may alter all the necessary styles, but it might be easier to write your own `.shorten` function. :]

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/S9uVh/30/

I have stored the original text for each title and also stored the shortened text for each title. On hover of `#element` the nearest h1's text is replaced with the original. On hover off its text is set back to the shortened version.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something/it wrong.

Usage is

```
.bind( eventType [, eventData], handler(eventObject) )
```

and

```
.unbind( [eventType] [, handler(eventObject)] )
```

Also **bind ()* is deprecated and you've should use *on()* and *off()*

Comment: Thanks for the nots on depreciation. I thought bind was fairly new.